# Your Guard is failing - Tor Server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, server, web-hosting

I'm having some major problems with my hidden services. I have about 10 sites hosted on my Pi. All of them are very low traffic sites (Maybe about 5-10 visits a day)

Only 2-4 sites are working out of those 10 most of the time even though they are set up the same.

CPU and RAM usage seem to be bellow 20%

I run on a gigabit fiber connection, and connected directly into a Archer C3200

In my tor logs I get:

> Your Guard x is failing more circuits than usual. Most likely this means the Tor network is overloaded. Success counts are 102/157. Use counts are 79/79. 102 circuits completed, 0 were unusable, 0 collapsed, and 54 timed out. For reference, your timeout cutoff is 60 seconds.

Comment: Is the rest of your internet connection okay? It's possible that your guard is being overloaded or that you, or your guards internet connection is experiencing issues. 10 sites means you need to publish 60 descriptors to the HSDirs and keep open about 30 circuits to the chosen introduction points. It's also possible that all that activity overloads low powered SOC devices like a Pi.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the comment. I have not experienced any issues with my internet. Solid 700Mbps up and down, and <5ms ping.
Each site has it's own entry with it's own internal port bound to port 80 
eg.:
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/HS1/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8081
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/HS2/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8082

Not fully sure if I understand "keep open about 30 circuits to the chosen introduction points" Could you explain that one please?

Thanks

Comment: A hidden service keeps connections open to a set of 3 (by default) introduction ports. For each service, you'll pick 3 introduction points and hold those connections open. Clients who want to contact you, connect to the introduction points to signal that they want to meet you at some rendezvous point. So with 10 onions, you'd need 30 of these connections open.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, but by keeping them "open", do you mean port forward like another 30+ ports to that IP?
Cause I mean, there is thousands of ports unused..
Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Actually I'm thinking of migrating my hidden services to my main server that I have to redeploy next week. I feel like running 10+ TOR services on a USB powered micro board just isn't a great idea in general XD

Gonna run them on a higher end Dell Poweredge :)
Thanks for your help

Comment: I think @canonizingironize was talking about keeping 30 TCP connections open, not ports forwards. And the hypothesis was that it's overloading your guard node, not your server. (I have a tor relay on a Raspberry Pi 3 by the way, and it maintains 1000s of inbound and outbound connections just fine.)

Comment: It's actually just 30 circuits, there would normally only be 1 TCP connection, which is the TLS tunnel that you build to your guard. Over that you send cells, circuits are a multiplexed over that TLS connection and cells have circuit ids which indicate which they belong to. So they're not TCP connections or ports kept open, just "circuits" but the software would need to keep track of them all. It might just be that it's too much for a Pi to have so many open.

Comment: please post your torrc so we'll take a deeper look. And what exact Pi model are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your guard node is failing, you could try using a different guard node if you really really want to:

[How to change the entry node?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/how-to-change-the-entry-node)

But according to this answer, you shouldn't have to:

[Should I choose a new guard if the network is overloaded?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/150/19270)

There are security implications to changing your guard node:

[Why is a longer guard rotation period with fewer guards better than the other way around?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/386/why-is-a-longer-guard-rotation-period-with-fewer-guards-better-than-the-other-wa)